# GRTS function not able to attain minimum distance in sample

Tags: r

I have very little experience with R.... I have been working on a non-stratified GRTS sample for a few days anow and am flummoxed as to why I am receiving this error every time I run the function:

Warning Message 1:

Stratum: None

Warning: Minimum distance between sites not attained after 150 attempts.

the resulting shapefile when I write to file contains points that are way within 800m, and there are bare stretches of streams with no sample sites.

The area in question is a total of 81201 m in length and I am trying for 45 base samples plus 20 oversamples, for a total of 65 sample sites. By my understanding, with the minimum distance at 800m, I should be able to get 101 sites, assuming that the points are spread evenly at equal intervals. So with that logic I SHOULD be able to get at least 65 random sites, right?

My input shapefiles are all projected in UTM Zone 11 N, so i know the issue is not an unprojected file.
I have run this exact script back in March 2023 and did not get this error. everything worked just fine.

The output shapefiles also don't include any information about the analysis, and instead only have an FID and geometry. From my understanding there should at least be a "Site" column with the Values "DesignID-SiteBegin" eg. "Site-1" "Site-2" etc.

I have tried with different minimum Distances (down to 300m) but I get the same error and same issues.
I have installed all required packages (sf, spsurvey, sp, rgdal).

this is my code:

```
## SET GRTS PARAMETERS

sframe<- sframein
n_base<- 45
stratum_var <- NULL
seltype <- "equal"
caty_var <- NULL
caty_n <- NULL
aux_var <- NULL
legacy_var <- NULL
legacy_sites <- NULL
legacy_stratum_var <- NULL
legacy_caty_var <- NULL
legacy_aux_var <- NULL
mindis <- 800
maxtry <- 150
n_over <- 20
n_near <- 2
wgt_units <- NULL
pt_density <- NULL
DesignID <- "Site"
SiteBegin <- 1
sep <- "-"
projcrs_check <- TRUE



# Set your INPUT Shapefile and OUTPUT Shapefile names.
inshape<- "inf_trial"
outshape<- "C:\\Data\\GRTS_Trials\\inf_out.shp"
outshape_over<- "C:\\Data\\GRTS_Trials\\inf_over.shp" 

set.seed(1597645932) 

#This reads your input shapefile
sframein <- read_sf(dsn = ".", layer = inshape)

##Run the Function
sites <- grts(sframein, n_base, stratum_var, seltype , caty_var , caty_n ,aux_var ,legacy_var,legacy_sites,legacy_stratum_var,legacy_caty_var,legacy_aux_var ,mindis ,maxtry,n_over,n_near,wgt_units ,pt_density,DesignID ,SiteBegin,sep,projcrs_check)
warnprnt()

#Write to file 
write_sf(sites[["sites_base"]][["geometry"]], outshape)
write_sf(sites[["sites_over"]][["geometry"]], outshape_over)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! I still don't understand what changed between now and the first time I ran it in march. I had no issues back then.